# Moving a banner in and out of viewport by its width (CSS Only)

Tags: css, animation, horizontal-scrolling

Ok, so I'm trying to make an infinite side-scrolling banner, and all is fine if I happen to know the width of what I'm moving. The problem is I don't. The idea is that we should accept a long text, an array of images or similar and make them appear from the right, move all the content to the left until everything has scrolled out of sight and then make it start again.

It should work now if we can get the `.sliding-banner` element to grow until it contains it's elements, but for some reason I can't achieve it. I'm missing something and don't know what! Argh!

What do you think?

Here's some CSS:

```
.sliding-banner {
    white-space: nowrap;
    animation: bannermove 30s linear infinite;
}

.sliding-banner > * {
    display: inline-block;
    float: none !important;
}

@keyframes bannermove {
    0% { transform: translateX(100%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

Thanks!

Edit: removed quotes around `bannermove` as per Red Mercury's suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Don't put the animation name into quotes.

`@keyframes "bannermove"` -> `@keyframes bannermove`

```css
.sliding-banner {
    white-space: nowrap;
    animation: bannermove 10s linear infinite;
}

@keyframes bannermove {
    0% { transform: translateX(100%); }
    100% { transform: translateX(-100%); }
}
```

```html
<div class="sliding-banner">
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
  <img src="http://placekitten.com/200/300"/>
<div/>
```

Comment: Thank you for your anwser, but it doesn't address the real problem. The banner does move, but when the content is too wide it doesn't expand to contain it.